# When compiling qt ld.exe: cannot find -ldb_cxx

Tags: bitcoin-qt-setup

When compiling bitcoin-qt on windows I get through

```
qmake "USE_UPNP=-" bitcoin-qt.pro
```

but when I run

```
make -f Makefile.Release
```

it returns

```
ld.exe: cannot find -ldb_cxx
```

which I am pretty sure is the Berkeley DB.  So I went into C:\deps\db-4.8.30.NC\build_unix and found db_cxx.h and added the path to the PATH before trying again only to fail

Comment: `-ldb` implies levelDB.

Comment: I though it implies library DB, because running ld.exe -l db_cxx has the same results.  How can I fix levelDB if that's what it is?

Comment: To think of it you may be correct. My bad!